# poll result from graph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api

```
"insights": {
    "data": [
      {
        "name": "post_stories_by_action_type",
        "period": "lifetime",
        "values": [
          {
            "value": {
              "share": 1,
              "like": 147,
              "comment": 70,
              "answer": 3426
            }
          }
        ],
        "title": "Lifetime Post Stories by action type",
        "description": "Lifetime: The number of stories created about your Page post, by action type. (Total Count)",
        "id": "xxxxxxxxx3_xxxxxxxxxx4/insights/post_stories_by_action_type/lifetime"
      }
```

This is the response that i received from graph api for a poll. I want to understand what is the field "answer" represent and how it is calulated ?

Comment: Well the initial assumption would be that this is the sum of all the answers given ... no?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention I have a business account and I have access to the insights of the page, and for this post the number of votes I am seeing are 2900. So, no, even if we assume comments are also part of the answer still 2900+70=2970. The numbers don't add up.